# How can i resolve the error the ionic is giving me

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to build an ionic 4 app on app store but i keep getting the error

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "create-h  MacOS": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-20T15_49_30_774Z-debug.log
```

what can i do to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with your bundle identifier name, it has to be with the format:

*com.yourname.yourappname*

That's only an example, but keep in mind that you should not use any special character for the package name.

Hope this helps you!